# Borderlands 2 Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode problem

Tags: borderlands-2

I just started playing the ultimate vault hunter mode and even though my level is around the enemies' level I'm fighting (even higher levels in some cases) and my weapons are the most powerful ones I can possibly get (via the golden box), I'm still hardly dealing any damage and both my shields and health are dropping in only a couple of hits. What's odd though is that I'm using the commando as my character class and my turrets are probably the only thing getting me through missions. They seem to be strong enough to beat my enemies but I can barely leave a scratch. Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: At this rate I won't be coming back. I've read over the ToS and I don't see anywhere in it that i must spell out abbreviations.

Comment: The editor is just making it easier to read, and ensures everyone understands what it is you're talking about.  That way, there's no confusion whatsoever.

Comment: @user64145 don't take the edits as a personal attack - as Frank says, they're just there to make things easier to read. Non-native English speakers may not understand 'lv', for example. Arqade is a collaborative site, so if you see a mistake I've made, please correct it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [UVHM wiki page](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Vault_Hunter_Mode) to see what`s changed. Specifically this:

- Enemy health generally increased 4x
- Enemy levels are automatically scaled above the character of the highest level, along with their health, attack, and loot level. Normal enemies will be the same level while greater enemies will be two levels higher. The change of level happens when characters gain a level or join/leave a game

Some other changes listed there tip you off that use of `slag` and elemental attacks may be essential to make progress in this mode.

Comment: I currently have slag, corrosive, and 2 shock weapons attached, all at level 58. I just don't get how I'm going down so fast. It seems like I'm forced to use my torrents in every engagement or else I'll go down.

Comment: Well, it all depends on your gear, build, and playstyle. It\`s a broad topic, but you can start with searching [some tips](https://www.google.ru/search?q=borderlands+2+uvhm+tips&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=wiiwUpq5HKeT4ATyvoGABw), like in the same [wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:UVHM_is_Ridiculous!). See what you can improve.